# Case in WHERE clause for condition oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have to write a query which have dynamic where clause. I have a column `gap_value` if the user sends a parameter 'P' then I need to fetch `gap_value>0` else if 'N' it should be `gap_value<0`.

```
SELECT   a.region_cd, a.plant_cd, a.wk_nbr
    FROM or_doh_plant_matrl_sm_t a
   WHERE a.wk_nbr IN (201322, 201323)
     AND a.plant_cd = '1115'
     AND a.gap_value >0
```

Without using a dynamic SQL. Can I use in `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT   a.region_cd, a.plant_cd, a.wk_nbr
    FROM or_doh_plant_matrl_sm_t a
   WHERE a.wk_nbr IN (201322, 201323)
     AND a.plant_cd = '1115'
     AND
     (
         (param = 'P' AND a.gap_value >0)
     OR  (param = 'N' AND a.gap_value <0)
     )
```